# Graph Implementation

Tags: python

I need to create a graph implementation from input files of the type formatted below where S will be the starting node from which I will implement a number of search algorithms. My question is how I turn this into a graph, right now I have written code to read the input file into an array of strings (w/ each input into the array being a line of the maze).

I was thinking I would then just find the starting node (where S is) and start building outward as I implement the search. Is this a better approach then creating all the nodes at the start? I will be using Python.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried. Part of SO's culture isn't to help solve vague problems, but to solve specific programming questions.

Comment: How about you ask ***yourself*** that question. Your question seems opinion-based to me.

Comment: Your question is very vague. It is not clear whether you are asking how to implement a graph data structure  in python, how to build a graph from the file you have, or if you want an algorithmic advice on building it beforehand or on the fly. Well, it isn't clear to me even *what* graph this file represents.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it would be to create a list of all nodes right after opening the file. In this example you will have a list of 220 nodes (10 x 22).

Then when you implement your search, you will create a new list (or graph or tree) of your searched nodes. (In the case of the A* search you will have a closedSet and an openSet etc.)